# Laravel, division by zero

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get the percentage of players who logged out while playing, so i have error: Division by zero. By the standard in the game 0 participants, 0 exited players.
In blade: `{{ $withTotal }}`, in controller

```
$withTotal = $this->getWithPerc();
return view('pages.crash', compact('withTotal'));
```

```
private function getWithPerc()
    {
      $withUsers = CrashBets::where(['round_id' => $this->game->id, 'status' => 1])->count();
      $NowithUsers = CrashBets::where(['round_id' => $this->game->id, 'status' => 0])->count();
      $totalUsers = $withUsers + $NowithUsers;
      $next1 = $totalUsers / 100;
      $next2 = $withUsers / $next1;
      return $next2;
    }
```

Getting the number of participants and those who have exited the game starts after placing the bets in the game. So after this i'm gettings this error. How i can fix this? Thanks guys :)

Comment: Don't divide by zero. If `$next1` is 0, then return 0, else divide as you already did.

Comment: Thank you! It was stupid error xD

Answer (score 1):

you can check if $next1 is not zero before making the second operation: here's the solution:

```
private function getWithPerc()
{
  $withUsers = CrashBets::where(['round_id' => $this->game->id, 'status' => 1])->count();
  $NowithUsers = CrashBets::where(['round_id' => $this->game->id, 'status' => 0])->count();
  $totalUsers = $withUsers + $NowithUsers;
  $next1 = $totalUsers / 100;

   if($next1 == 0) 
       return 0;

  $next2 = $withUsers / $next1;
  return $next2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!